# how can i make google sheet itrate over columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

[image]

I have a sheet like this  how can make a cell in front of x under the sum column get the sum of the x count column and y get the sum y count column
of course, I use sum function on both but the issue I face is how to make the z ,x1,y1,z1 the same I try to fill it down but as you see in the picture it is wrong
how can I do it for 100 row ?

Answer (score 1):

This formula seems to give the result you want:

```
={"Header","Sum";
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(D1:1),COUNTA(D1:1),1),
    ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(D2:AJ10)),{SEQUENCE(ROWS(D2:AJ10),1,1,0)}))}
```

It places the two column labels in the first row, then transposes all of the header values into a vertical column in A2:A, but prevents any blank rows by using `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`, and a check for the number of header values to transpose.

The main result is the Sums, calculated using `MMULT`.  You need to enter the range of the cells you are going to sum over - I've used D2:AJ10, entered twice in the formula.  `MMULT` can slow down performance the more cells it has to review, but this seemed fine for 33 columns by 9 rows.  Test it out in your actual sheet, and report back if any issues.

[image]

REFERENCES:

[ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en) To limit size of an array result, by # rows and # columns

[MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en&ref_topic=3105706) The matrix product of two matrices.  Can be used for summing, if one matrix is one dimensional (eg. a row or a column) with values of just 1.